# Saber que palabra aparece antes que otra en el diccionario en java

Tags: java

Hola me gustaría saber como puedo obtener que palabra aparece antes en el diccionario, a partir de dos palabras que introduzca un usuario en java. Muchas gracias. Por ejemplo, si el usuario introduce la palabra `hola` y la palabra `adiós`, cuál sería el método para saber cual de las 2 aparece antes en el `diccionario`.

```
private static Scanner sc;
    
    private static String pidePalabra1() {
        
        System.out.print("Introduzca una palabra: ");
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
    
    private static String pidePalabra2() {
        
        System.out.print("Introduzca otra palabra");
        return sc.nextLine();
    }
    
    private static void muestraInfo(String palabra1, String palabra2) {
        
        System.out.printf("Palabra1: %s \tPalbra2: %s = %s")
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        String palabra1 = pidePalabra1();
        String palabra2 = pidePalabra2();
        
        muestraInfo (palabra1, palabra2);
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Sugiero que leas [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/). Solo debes saber buscar las cosas. Por ejemplo, en este caso quieres comparar strings. Es buena idea comenzar por ver las funciones disponibles de la clase [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*¿Cómo se organizan las palabras en el diccionario?*

Se ordena a partir de la primera letra de la palabra. Cuando las palabras empiezan por la misma letra, se tiene en cuenta también la segunda. Cuando coinciden en las dos o más primeras letras se ordenan teniendo en cuenta la tercera, la cuarta, y así sucesivamente...

entonces para realizar ello podrias hace uso del metodo [compareTo()](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_compareto.asp) el cual  compara dos cadenas `lexicográficamente`.de querer comparar cadenas que contengan mayúscula quiza te sea mas factible usar el metodo [compareToIgnorecase](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_comparetoignorecase.asp)

Ejemplo:

```
    String palabra1="amanecer";
    String palabra2="amanecio";
    
    /*
    Salida del metodo compareTo()
    
    Un int valor:
    0 si la cadena es igual a la otra cadena.
    < 0 si la cadena es lexicográficamente menor que la otra cadena
    > 0 si la cadena es lexicográficamente mayor que la otra cadena (más caracteres
     */
    
    int valorInt=palabra1.compareTo(palabra2);
    
    if(valorInt>0){System.out.println(palabra2+" aparece antes en el diccionario");}
    if(valorInt<0){System.out.println(palabra1+" aparece antes en el diccionario");}
    if(valorInt==0){System.out.println("son iguales");}
  //resultado: amanecer aparece antes en el diccionario
```